# create specific DB-Admin Account

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

is it possible to create in Mysql an admin-user that can modify everything exept the mysql-root user?

Thanks,
starflighter

Comment: Welcome to the site. What is the MySQL version(x,y,z)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the welcome :), it is 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2

Comment: Single table record (including a record from mysql.users table) cannot be a granting object (grantable level). The task cannot be solved using std. granting system.

Comment: @Akina nice to know, i think this is the right answer.

Comment: I have never tested if it is possible to create a trigger on `mysql.user` table. You may test. If it is possible, you can check current user and affected record data, and eject action by error signalling if needed...

Comment: Tested. Impossible - triggers cannot be defined for system tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Akina posted in comments:

> Tested. Impossible - triggers cannot be defined for system tables

You can not do that in the moment...

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's possible. As per MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-users.html)
After connecting to the server as root, you can add new accounts. The following example uses CREATE USER and GRANT statements to set up four accounts:

**For example**

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'finley'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'finley'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE USER 'finley'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'finley'@'%'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql> GRANT RELOAD,PROCESS ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
mysql> CREATE USER 'dummy'@'localhost';
```

The accounts created by those statements have the following properties:

- Two accounts have a user name of **finley**. Both are superuser accounts
  with full privileges to do anything. The `'finley'@'localhost'`
  account can be used only when connecting from the local host. The
  `'finley'@'%'` account uses the **'%'** wildcard for the host part, so it
  can be used to connect from any host.

  The `'finley'@'localhost'` account is necessary if there is an
  anonymous-user account for localhost. Without the
  `'finley'@'localhost'` account, that anonymous-user account takes
  precedence when finley connects from the local host and finley is
  treated as an anonymous user. The reason for this is that the
  anonymous-user account has a more specific Host column value than the
  `'finley'@'%'` account and thus comes earlier in the user table sort
  order. (user table sorting is discussed in 
  [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connection-access.html).)
- The **'admin'@'localhost'** account can be used only by **admin** to connect
  from the **local host**. It is granted the RELOAD and PROCESS
  administrative privileges. These privileges enable the admin user to
  execute the **mysqladmin reload**, **mysqladmin refresh**, and **mysqladmin
  flush-xxx commands**, as well as **mysqladmin processlist** . No privileges
  are granted for accessing any databases. You could add such
  privileges using GRANT statements.
- The `'dummy'@'localhost'` account has no password (which is insecure
  and not recommended). This account can be used only to connect from
  the local host. No privileges are granted. It is assumed that you
  will grant specific privileges to the account using GRANT statements.

Comment: This means the user finley@% has the permission to delete other superusers or not?
I want that finley is allowed to create/modify/delete specific users for their own database, but not superusers like root.
How can i do that?
Maybe i don't unterstand you correctly... why do i need the admin@localhost when I have ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to finley?

Comment: The answer does not answer the question. *Yes It's possible* I doubt it. If you're sure that it's possible - show the command(s) which allows `admin@localhost` to alter `user@localhost` but forbids `root@localhost` altering. Assume that in the beginning `admin@localhost` have all privileges granted.

Comment: @ Akinae,what you have **doubt** it.